# Can’t convert Latin1 to utf-8? Not a coder

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I live in the US, wanting to set up a website using **cPanel**. I bought a **InstaWebsite** that's written in *Latin1* (England)(this is supposed to be an option in the Character Set of Files list) and need it translated to UTF-8.

I try to import the file “*store database.text*” and nothing happens but an empty file is created(&Latin1 is not an option). Can anyone help?  Are there any easy fixes.

I spoke w/a tech person that hosts my domain on **InMotionHosting**.  I  He suggested asking you for help. I don't know how to code. I also sent an email to the fellow I bought this from – he’s in England & am waiting for help from him.

This is what it does when I try to import using **UTF-8**:

**SQL query:**

```
CREATE TABLE `address_book` (
`address_book_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`customers_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`entry_gender` CHAR( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`entry_company` VARCHAR( 32 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`entry_firstname` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`entry_lastname` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`entry_street_address` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`entry_suburb` VARCHAR( 32 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`entry_city` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`entry_state` VARCHAR( 32 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`entry_postcode` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`entry_country_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`entry_zone_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY ( `address_book_id` ) ,
KEY `idx_address_book_customers_id` ( `customers_id` )
) TYPE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =100;
```

**MySQL said:**

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=100' at line 17

Comment: Do you have any non-English characters?  Such as accented European characters?

Comment: How are you doing the "import"?  Is there any problem with the character set?

Comment: You should use InnoDB, not MyISAM.

Comment: If the site is designed to work on Latin-1 you can't just "translate" it. It's like trying to translate a hairdresser to work in 125 volts. But it should work as is because Latin-1 can store all English language characters. But your error has nothing to do with text encoding (who told you that?)

Answer (score 1):

```
) TYPE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =100;
```

This code is incorrect. If you got this SQL file as part of a software package you bought, get a refund -- it's obviously an untested piece of junk.

The proper way to specify a storage engine for a MySQL table is using the `ENGINE` option:

```
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```

Comment: Deprecated since 4.0 -- about 16 years ago; Error since 5.5, a few years ago.

Comment: Just as Rick says ([ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html#create-table-options)). I used to find this error in my early days as developer. Source code is probably from those years.

Comment: I wish I could get a refund - he states none & hasn't responded to email or site ?'s.  I'll try the coding suggestions and hope.  Thanks for your time everyone.  You all are awesome!

Comment: @DarcyY Outside the realm of programming recommendations, but: If you paid for the software using a credit card or PayPal, you can open a dispute with your credit card company or with PayPal (respectively).